# If X is normal, A closed in X, U an open set in X that contains A, find a set V open in X that contains A whose closure is contained in U

Tags: general-topology

My attempt at a solution: since X is normal, it is regular, and this implies U is regular as a subspace of X.  Now, since A is closed in X, it is closed in U.  If A=U, we're done; U is closed since A is closed, so  U itself is the set V we are looking for (closure of U is just U in this case).  If A is not equal to U, we can find some point x in U that isn't in A, and apply regularity: we can find open, disjoint sets U', V such that U' contains x and V contains A.  Then since U is closed in itself, the closure of V must be a subset of U, as desired, so this is the set we're looking for.

The problem with this solution that was pointed out to me is that I made the mistake of conflating the closure of V in U with the closure of V in X.  But is there a way to salvage this proof, or do we need to do something completely different?

Answer (score 1):

You need something completely different (and much simpler). Let $B=X\setminus U$; then $A$ and $B$ are disjoint closed subsets of the normal space $X$, so there are are disjoint open sets $V$ and $W$ such that $A\subseteq V$ and $B\subseteq W$. $V\cap W=\varnothing$, so $V\subseteq X\setminus W$. Finally $X\setminus W$ is closed, so

$$\operatorname{cl}V\subseteq X\setminus W\subseteq X\setminus B=U\,.$$

Comment: Oh!  Thanks, that is a lot simpler, guess I was really overthinking this one.

Comment: @Alex: You’re welcome.  (It happens to all of us occasionally.)